# MySQL compound or separate index including foreign key

Tags: mysql, indexing, key, innodb

Given below are 2 tables using InnoDB:

```
devices
{
   sid - primary key bigint autoincrement unique,
   imei - char (15)
}
```

And table:

```
positions
{
   pid - primary key bigint autoincrement unique,
   sid - foreign key referencing devices,
   timeUtc - datetime,
   lat - float,
   lon - float
}
```

On the server I have 500 devices sending gps coordinates each 10 seconds (most of the time each 30 minutes).
All coordinates are stored into table positions.
Table positions has 20 Mio records.
Positions older that 3 months are delted each 30 minutes so table **DOES NOT** keep growing infinetly and keeps being around 20 Mio records.

Target query to run fast is:

```
SELECT lat,lon FROM positions 
WHERE sid=SOME_DEV_ID 
WHERE timeUtc >= SOME_DATETIME 
  AND timeUtc < ANOTHER_DATE_TIME
```

ORDER BY timeUtc ASC

I created index: `INDEX time_sid (timeUtc, sid) asc`

My query is still slow [30 secs for a 24 hours period `ANOTHER_DATE_TIME-SOME_DATETIME` where result  is around 2000-5000 result rows for a single device] while using the index and memory pool size is 1 GB.

MySQL admininstrator statistics show: data size 0.9 GB and index size 1.7 GB.

Index hitrate is 999 of 1000 as engine status says.

When just using `timeUtc` without involving `sid` it returns many rows but extremely fast [0.2 sec]. But when involving `sid` it goes super slow. I changed also order of `timeUtc` and sid in the query without any change.

Should I use index for `timeUtc` column only and sid or I should leave indices as they are?

Would memory pool increase lead to much better results? I ask because ordering more memory would lead to signifficantly more costs per month on my virtual server so an answer 'just try' is not that easy.

What is so wrong that on 20 mio records DB I have so poor results?

Comment: Change the order of columns **in the index**: `INDEX time_sid ( sid, timeUtc )`. Changing the order of conditions in the query is aimless, MySql can do it by itself during optimalization if needed.

Comment: Thank you, Kordirko! It is amazing how your simple solution become genial! And it is so logical when I made second thoughts. Thank you once again - now it is bullet fast.